# How to access "extra" Hashie in omniauth-facebook callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth

In a Rails app I had the following code updating the user's profile from their Facebook profile

```
self.update_attributes( :location => request.env["omniauth.auth"].extra.raw_info.location.name )
```

I'm in the process of updating Rail and gems, and now this line is failing.

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass):
```

Looking at the output, I see

```
...
extra: !map:Hashie::Mash 
  raw_info: !map:Hashie::Mash 
...
```

How can I access attributes within this Hashie?